# Maximizing Directional Derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$$ f_{(x,y)} = x^2 - 2y^2 + 3x $$

In what direction from (1,2) should we proceed so that the change so that the change in *f* in that direction would increase most rapidly?

I'm guessing you would have to maximize the Fx and Fy, other than that I'm pretty much lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient of a function points in the direction of steepest ascent.

Comment: so I did that and I have: <2x +3 , -4y> for the gradient.

Comment: That's right. So now you want to evaluate that at the point (1,2).

Comment: right, so it's <5,-8>. and so that's the direction vector of f?